# React : Pass conditional renderings data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Assuming that this is a Toggle component to hide and display data, when called alone it's working perfectly.

Now I have a dashboard.js where I will be calling this component, but I only want to output the data, keeping the toggle switch separated in his file.

How do I pass data from the Toggle component to the Dashboard component ?
Still newbie in React and from what I learned apparently you can't pass data from child to parent.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Toggle extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={isShowBody: false} 
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        this.setState({isShowBody: !this.state.isShowBody})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div   >
                <div  >
                <span className="switch switch-sm" >
                              <label>                                    
                                <input type="checkbox" name="select" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}/>
                                <span />
                              </label>
                            </span> 
                </div>
                {this.state.isShowBody ? 
                    <div>
                        Data test
                    </div>
                : null}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might give you more insight in addition to what the previous answer is: Using Redux would definitely a good option but that entirely depends on the complexity of the project.

```
export class Toggle extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            isShowBody: false
        } 
    }

    handleClick = (event) => {
        this.setState({ isShowBody: !this.state.isShowBody })
    }

    checkbox = () => {
        return (
            <span className="switch switch-sm" >
                <label>                                    
                    <input type="checkbox" name="select" onClick={() => this.handleClick(this)}/>
                </label>
            </span>
        )
    }

    dataTest = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                Data test
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.checkbox()}
                {this.state.isShowBody && this.dataTest()}
                /**
                * You can extract this dataSet into another component as well where you can pass initial visibility value as this.state.isShowBody
                * for example
                * <Dataset visibility={this.state.isShowBody} />
                * */
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Now I understand things better. You split the code into functions and called them, while the fuction are reusable elsewhere. I will try your code later but for now it seems the right way to do it. Thanks again.

Comment: The function are working, but the Dataset is not. Did you mean dataTest ?

Comment: You can live the functions as it is if the div that contains data test is only a normal UI div, if this div contains complex UI and requires a lot of state variable to interact with, it makes sense to extract it into another component such as <Datatest /> and now you can move all the UI of this div to this newly created component and use it here as normal component

Comment: I see. But when I'm moving the data div to another component, both component of buttons and displaying data doesn't interact with each other, meaning that I can't hide/show data in another component.

Comment: You can show the component itself with the state variable in parent component

Comment: Liker using `value` inside the declaration of the component?

Comment: for eg {this.state.isShowBody && <DataTest />}

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parent to have information the child has you need to left up the state to the parent component and pass it to the child.

If your component has the potential to become bigger, keeping lifting up the state will become a problem so consider using a state management library like Redux.

Comment: I don't' know if it will solve my problem but I will be looking at Redux. Thank you.

Comment: Also sorry for being noob, how do you know a child component from a parent component ?

Comment: A component can be a child and a parent at the same time. A component is parent to all the components that are rendered inside its render function but a child component to a component in which it itself is rendered. Let me know if that was clear to you.

Comment: So basically if a component is called on another one it's his child. If I understood correctly.

Comment: So yes If you have for example component Dashboard...and side Dashboard you use Toogle somewhere in there then Toogle will be a child of Dashboard and Dashboard will be the parent.

Comment: Yea. Anyway thank you I still have much to learn.